# Android Spring Rest Template using MockRestServiceServer with Build tool 1.1

Tags: android, mockito, powermock, spring-android

I using Spring Android Rest Template to perform HTTP request. I was testing like so :

```
package com.mnubo.platform.android.sdk.internal.user.services.impl;

import com.mnubo.platform.android.sdk.models.users.User;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.GET;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.method;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
public class DummyTest {

    private MyApiImpl myApi;
    private MockRestServiceServer myapiMockServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    myApi = new MyApiImpl("ACCESS_TOKEN");//break here

    myapiMockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(myApi.getRestTemplate());
    }

    @Test
    public void testRestClient() throws Exception {


    final User expectedUser = new User();
    expectedUser.setUsername("test");
    expectedUser.setLastname("lastname");

    myapiMockServer.expect(requestTo("http://my-service.com/user/test"))
            .andExpect(method(GET))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(this.convertToJsonString(expectedUser), APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));

    User user = myApi.userOperations().getUser("test");
    userMockServer.verify();
    }
}
```

All of this was working correctly using the RoboelectricTestRunner. But, yesterday Android Studio updated and asked me to update the build tool version to 1.1.0. (com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0).

This version now include supports for Unit testing. See https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

The problem : I can't create `MyApiImpl` anymore because it creates a RestTemplate. This RestTemplate use org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory and in this class constructor, methods from the org.apache.http package are used.

These methods raised an exception : Eg: `Method getSocketFactory in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory`

Well, I mocked successfully the getSocketFactory using PowerMock but then I had to mock the `register` method of SchemeRegistry that is only locally accessible from the constructor ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/3.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java)).

So I gave up trying to mock all of the shenanigans happening inside the RestTemplate and decided to directly mock the RestTemplate.

I need help to mock it correctly so that the `MockRestServiceServer` can still be used in my test, because right now, the `myapiMockServer.verify()` assertion fails.

**Update**
I'm still unable to use the `MockRestServiceServer` to test my Api, but I managed to test each individual `OperationImpl` using a mock of the `RestTemplate` like so :

```
public class DummyOperationTest {

    private DummyOperation dummyOperation;

    private RestTemplate mockedRestTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    dummyOperation = new DummyOperationImpl(PLATFORM_BASE_URL, mockedRestTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

    String calledUrl = PLATFORM_BASE_URL + "/objects?update_if_exists=true";
    when(mockedRestTemplate.postForObject(calledUrl, expectedSmartObject, SmartObject.class)).thenReturn(expectedSmartObject);

    smartObjectService.create(expectedSmartObject, true);
    verify(mockedRestTemplate, atMost(1)).postForObject(calledUrl, expectedSmartObject, SmartObject.class);


    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this still doesn't test the whole request execution. I can't validate that oAuth authentication is correctly added to the headers, or if the conversion of the server response is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was a matter of mocking. I didn't understood everything correctly but I finally worked it out. Here is an a example that shows how to proceed :

```
package com.mnubo.platform.android.sdk.internal;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.method;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.response.MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({
        Log.class,
        PlainSocketFactory.class,
        SSLSocketFactory.class,
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class,
        ConnManagerParams.class,
        AbstractHttpClient.class
})
public class DummyTest {

    private final String USER_ACCESS_TOKEN = "user_token";

    private final PlainSocketFactory mockedPlainSocketFactory = mock(PlainSocketFactory.class);
    private final SSLSocketFactory mockedSSLSocketFactory = mock(SSLSocketFactory.class);
    private final SchemeRegistry mockedSchemeRegistry = mock(SchemeRegistry.class);
    private final DefaultHttpClient mockedHttpClient = mock(DefaultHttpClient.class);
    private final HttpParams mockedHttpParams = mock(HttpParams.class);


    private DummyApiImpl dummyApi = new DummyApiImpl(USER_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    protected MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(Log.class);
        mockStatic(PlainSocketFactory.class);
        mockStatic(SchemeRegistry.class);
        mockStatic(SSLSocketFactory.class);
        mockStatic(ConnManagerParams.class);

        whenNew(SchemeRegistry.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockedSchemeRegistry);
        whenNew(DefaultHttpClient.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockedHttpClient);
        when(PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()).thenReturn(mockedPlainSocketFactory);
        when(SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()).thenReturn(mockedSSLSocketFactory);
        when(mockedHttpClient.getParams()).thenReturn(mockedHttpParams);

        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(dummyApi.getRestTemplate());

    }

    @Test
    public void doOperationTest() throws Exception {

        final User testUser = new User();

        mockUserServiceServer.expect(requestTo(expectedUrl("/users/test")))
                .andExpect(method(POST))
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andRespond(withSuccess());

        dummyApi.userOperations().createUser("test", testUser);
        mockUserServiceServer.verify();
    }
}
```

The problem occurred when the constructor of the Api was called. This classe extends `AbstractOAuth2ApiBinding` which constructor create a `RestTemplate`. This is this object that requires multiple level of mocking.

Once you have mocked the required element to create the `RestTemplate`, the rest is very easy, thanks to the mock server!